# ASP.NET requests queued, can I identify what these requests are?

Tags: asp.net, request-queueing

It seems helpful to find out what kind of requests currently in the queue when the queue blocked. Are there any ways for me to know the infomation of them? e.g. request url, client ip, cookie, body...

Comment: Are you trying to identify performance issues, if a specific IP address is causing a certain timeout, specific pages?

Answer (score 1):

You could look into [ASP.NET tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx) in the interim. This will list things like page processing time, IP address being request, page being requested as well as session, form, request and application variables currently in use.

However, these are all recorded after request has been served, so does not show a live update, but it should help you see what

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any ways for me to know the information of them?

Technically slow requests will have long duration in your IIS logs.  Use [LogParser](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Log-Parser-Studio-cd458765) to see which requests taken the longest and use max times along with standard deviation to spot requests that may have been queued.

Using LogParser and this query

```
/*  Returns the number of times a particular page (in this case .as* files) was hit, with the average, minimum, and maximum time taken, along with the standard deviation.  */


SELECT TO_LOWERCASE(cs-uri-stem) AS csUriStem, COUNT(*) AS Hits, DIV ( MUL(1.0, SUM(time-taken)), Hits )  AS AvgTime, 
SQRROOT ( SUB ( DIV ( MUL(1.0, SUM(SQR(time-taken)) ), Hits ) , SQR(AvgTime) ) ) AS StDev, Max(time-taken) AS Max, Min(time-taken) AS Min, 
TO_REAL(STRCAT(TO_STRING(sc-status), STRCAT('.', TO_STRING(sc-substatus)))) AS Status, Min(TO_LOCALTIME(date)) AS LastUpdate 
FROM '[LOGFILEPATH]'
 WHERE cs-uri-stem like '%.as%' GROUP BY TO_LOWERCASE(cs-uri-stem), TO_REAL(STRCAT(TO_STRING(sc-status), STRCAT('.', TO_STRING(sc-substatus)))) HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
order by AvgTime desc
```